# use new value of variables in extended class

Tags: php, class

This is my example code :

```php
class Dad {
    protected $name = 'Alex';

    public function setName($string)
    {
        $this->name = $string;
    }
}


class Son extends Dad{

    public function showName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

and i use that classes like this:

```php
            $dad = new Dad();
            $dad->setName('John');


            $son = new Son();
            echo $son->showName();//it echo Alex but i need to echo John
```

I use many protected variable in parent and child class and this is just example.
How i can use new value from protected variables in child class ?

Comment: When you instantiate an object from a class then that object lives on its own. So in the code above where you create two different objects they will not be connected in any way and object 2 can not know you set $name on object 1. It would be very helpful with another example of what you're trying to do as the code above doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 objects. The default name in the object is 'Alex'. Therefore, when you create a new object and don't explicitly give it a name, it will use 'Alex' because that is the default.

```
$p = new Dad;
// name is Alex.

$q = new Son;
// name is Alex

$p->setName('John'); // Now the name of $p is John
$q->setName('Beto'); // Now the name of $q is Beto. $p remains unchanged.
```

This is the point of objects, that they are separate.

If you wanted a way to change the default name, then you could do this.

```
class Dad
{
    protected $name;
    static protected $defaultName = 'Alex';
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = self::$defaultName;
    }
    public function showName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public static function setDefault($name)
    {
        self::$defaultName = $name;
    }
}
```

Now:

```
$p = new Dad; // $p->name is 'Alex'
Dad::setDefault('Bernie');
$q = new Dad; // $q->name is 'Bernie', $p is not changed
$r = new Dad; // $r->name is 'Bernie'
Dad::setDefault('Walt');
$t = new Dad; // $t->name is Walt
```

Hope this helps.